# Do programs run in S1 or S2 power saving state?

Tags: windows-7

So there are S1-S5 sleeping state for sleep mode in a computer. S3 should be normal standby and all programs would be paused and not running. How about S1 and S2? By the way I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those rare questions that has a very simple answer: No... no code of any sort runs in anything except S0.

This is OS-independent (as long as your OS complies with ACPI power state definitions... I'm not aware of any even barely significant OS that doesn't).

"Then how does the system transition from one S-state to another, when neither is S0?" Simple - all such transitions go through S0 as an intermediate step. An example: Laptops can be put in standby but configured to go to hibernate (S4) if the battery falls below a certain percentage of charge. To do that the machine has to go to S0, write RAM to the hibernate file, then go to S4 (which puts the power controller in the normal "plugged in but power off" state).

S5 btw is not "sleeping", it is full power off. S4 is defined as hibernation.

Comment: Thank you. So as long as I want a program to run, I have to just let the computer keeps running....

Comment: Yes, 'fraid so.

Comment: Any suggestion to save some energy and power cost if I need to keep running a very simple program with my desktop?

Comment: Ah, now we get into "it depends" :) In Windows I can set my desktop to a "Power saver" mode. This should reduce your CPU clock speed, assuming your system is recent enough to support that. Keep the program and all of the files it needs on the same hard drive as the OS, and configure the "plan settings" under "power saver" to spin down the hard drives after a minute or so of inactivity. That's about the most you can do, without dedicating a laptop or some low-power PC to the task.

Comment: I heard that a harddisk life would be shorter if power saving scheme turns it off then on instead of keep spinning. Do you think it is true?

Comment: No. It is true that many failures happen at power on, but in this case power is not actually being taken away and then applied again. The drive is just told "don't spin the platter any more", and "ok, spin up now". It's true that spinning up loads the motor more than when it's just operating, but motor and bearing failures are easily the rarest type of hard drive failure. Head crashes are very rare too (except for a few models that had design errors). Most HD failures are actually in the electronics, and the electronics are staying powered in these cases, so... I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks. But people over here have very different option: http://www.overclock.net/t/1515480/what-happen-if-i-set-hdd-auto-turn-off-after-like-5-minutes-but-i-am-downloading-stuff-with-torrent

Comment: Well, I disagree, for reasons already given. I believe they  think that the drive goes through a full power cycle. Even if it did, I've yet to see any studies that show a correlation between number of full power cycles (this is recorded in SMART data) and failure rates; drives are rated for FAR more power cycles than you are ever likely to put them through. Again: Almost all drive failures these days are in the controller board, and the board remains powered when the drive is spun down for power savings. That's my (I will bashfully claim) well-founded opinion, and I'm sticking to it. :)

Comment: @Annie: maybe obvious, but turning off your monitor saves quite a lot to the total power consumption of your computer ([about 20% according to this site, depending on your setup](http://michaelbluejay.com/electricity/computers.html))